# How to make a request for sandbox paypal using jQuery?

Tags: ajax, json, paypal

https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/ebook/PP_Sandbox_UserGuide/testing_ec_with_nvp.html

I created paypal sandbox account both buyer and seller. In seller account i created one buy button then i include in my application. the NVP is working fine and give's ack but How to call the  webservice in $.ajax. How to set the header and how to pass as JSOn? thanks in advance

Comment: Could you show what you've tried so far? Your approach?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the PayPal API's through jQuery. This sort of thing *must* be processed server-side.